# Ionic Applow Capactor , firebase notification warning, ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement need advice

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-appflow

I have recently started using Ionic Capacitor. I have migrated my  notification successfully for Android using the following tutorial
https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase/

But when it comes to IOS i am getting the following warning:

```
ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.
```

I have used a "Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)" certifaction for my Firebase setup.

And in Ionic Appflow, i have also added a new App Store Provisioning Profile.

Must i do anything else?

Answer (score 3):

Check the prerequisites:

https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase/#prerequisites

In particular the number 3:
[Ensure Push Notification capabilities have been enabled](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev88ff319e7) in your application in Xcode

That link explains how to add Capabilities, you have to search for Push and double click it or drag it to the Signing & Capabilities pane.

[image: capabilities screen]

Comment: How do we preform this setting using Ionic Capacitor?

Comment: the link explains it, and the screenshot should help to, click on the + sign next to "Capability" and then double click on "Push notifications"

Comment: I do not have an Apple device that runs Xcode. I usually build on appflow and then use a ipad to run the app. Is there away to do this without xcode?

Comment: I don't think so. You can probably write some node script that adds it using https://github.com/apache/cordova-node-xcode, but no idea how